# MySQL - Update with Join suddenly takes forever

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a main table **MainTable**. has about 4.5M rows.
This is it's create query:

```
create table MainTable(
   status_day date DEFAULT NULL, 
   i_station_id int DEFAULT NULL, 
   i_TZ int DEFAULT NULL, 
   CID int DEFAULT NULL, 
   Calc1 double DEFAULT NULL, 
   Calc2 double DEFAULT NULL, 
   ...
   Calc80 double DEFAULT NULL, 
UNIQUE KEY uniqueindex (status_day, i_station_id, i_TZ, CID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need to update several feilds with values from another **TEMP** table. It has about 760K rows, and it's create statement:

```
create temporary table TEMP (
   status_day date DEFAULT NULL, 
   i_station_id int DEFAULT NULL, 
   i_TZ int DEFAULT NULL, 
   CID int DEFAULT NULL,, 
   Calc13 double DEFAULT NULL, 
   Calc14 double DEFAULT NULL, 
   Calc17 double DEFAULT NULL, 
   Calc24 double DEFAULT NULL, 
   Calc68 double DEFAULT NULL, 
   Calc70 double DEFAULT NULL, 
UNIQUE KEY indexxx (status_day, i_station_id, i_TZ, CID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

For some reason this Update query:

Takes ~ 3 hours. Does that make sense? seems way too long to me.

```
update MainTable as A join TEMP as B on
        (A.status_day = B.status_day and 
        A.i_station_id = B.i_station_id and 
        A.i_TZ = B.i_TZ and 
        A.CID = B.CID) 
set 
   A.Calc13 = B.Calc13, 
   A.Calc14 = B.Calc14, 
   A.Calc17 = B.Calc17, 
   A.Calc24 = B.Calc24, 
   A.Calc68 = B.Calc68, 
   A.Calc70 = B.Calc70
```

This is the results of

```
Explain select 
    * 
from MainTable as a join TEMP as b on
    (a.status_day = b.status_day and 
    a.i_station_id = b.i_station_id and 
    a.i_TZ = b.i_TZ and 
    a.CID = b.CID) 




ID     select_type   table    type    possible_keys  key          key_len rows  
1      SIMPLE        b        ALL     indexxx                             692967
1      SIMPLE        a        ref     uniqueindex    uniqueindex  23      1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks? :)

**Update**: Answer: An increase of memory and CPU to the server solved this immediately.

Comment: Better add number of rows from explain plan. 
Also are there any duplicate values among the fields you join on, like empty fields? This could make your update find a very high number of matching rows and would explain the long execution time.

Comment: Hey:) no duplicates on the joined fields they are a unique key on both tables... 
I added the number of rows to the explain output

Comment: I once had a similar problem and it was the Disk I/O. As rhavendc wrote 3 hours are way too much for the query. But your query seems fine and the number of rows is really not that high. Could it be that there was another big transaction running at the same time? I would test the query on another server if possible and if not you could make copies of the tables, rebuild indices and test the query with the copies to make sure it has nothing to do with the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure why the query took 3-hrs, that's absurd. Maybe there's something wrong with the columns you're joining, but you can make also a query like this:

```
UPDATE MainTable A, TEMP B
SET
     Calc13 = B.Calc13, 
     Calc14 = B.Calc14, 
     Calc17 = B.Calc17, 
     Calc24 = B.Calc24, 
     Calc68 = B.Calc68, 
     Calc70 = B.Calc70
WHERE
     A.status_day = B.status_day
     AND A.i_station_id = B.i_station_id
     AND A.i_TZ = B.i_TZ
     AND A.CID = B.CID
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the 3-hour cost is building a huge "rollback" log.

I would build a look around updating 1000 rows (or less) per iteration.  Or, more simply, update all rows for one `TEMP.status_day` in a single `UPDATE`, then move on to the next `TEMP.status_day`.  Either a Stored Procedure, or application code could be used.

If you do that, be sure to `COMMIT` after each `UPDATE`.  (Or simply use `autocommit=1`.)

[*More on chunking*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).